# I am getting this warning - Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in.. What must I do?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, null, database-connection

I am trying to do a select query on a mysql db table through php and I am getting the

> Warning : "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ....\Testing\testingdb.php on line 29.".

Isn't the `$con` class variable within the scope of the function `get_Article_MetaData()`? If yes, then why is setting to 'null' while executing `mysqli_query()`?

```
<?php

class db_connect {
    private $host;<br>
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    private $con;
    
    function _construct($hostname, $uname, $pword, $database)
    {
        $this->host = $hostname;
        $this->username = $uname;
        $this->password = $pword;
        $this->dbname = $database;
        
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);    
        
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: "; echo mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        else{
            echo "Connection successfully established.";
        }
    }
    
    function get_Article_MetaData(){
       $result = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT title, abstract, publish_date, author_name FROM articles, author where author_id=author_id");
        if($result == false){
            echo "Empty DB";
        }
        else{
            $rows = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
               $rows[]=$row;
            }
            foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
                echo "Key: $key; Value: $value\n";
            }
        }
    }
    
}

    $connection = new db_connect("localhost","root","","article_collection");
    $connection->get_Article_MetaData();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used single `_` (underscore) for a constructor should be two,

```
function __construct($hostname, $uname, $pword, $database)
```